# Ignoring a resource if it exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Now I did my fair share of googling - and people say it can't be done.

I have some SSM parameters that are only good when deployed first time (and they have to be deployed). Then, a step function changes them. It's a "date" value - it is created with default value initially, but then the lambda updates it. As you can guess, making any changes to my deployments REDEPLOYS parameters that shouldn't be touched anymore - returning them to default (because TF noticed a change). Any way to work around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, lifecycle meta-arguments

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
     
    ]
  }
```

Specifically, in the case of [aws_ssm_parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter)

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [value]
  }
```

Comment: How a lambda running in AWS will not be able to change a resource there? Terraform doesn't block the resources, it will only avoid changes made by `terraform` itself. If you go to the console, you will be able to change it as well. The best way to avoid issues like that is giving only read permission to your lambda, or using specific roles, you should treat it at the `IAM` level, not on `terraform`.